# How to have a row with fixed height as last row in Grid with percents

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to have a height in my grid for my last row, but it is always ignored.
Here is what I want in the end, that works, but the size of my last row varies with the size of the screen :
[image]

This is the style I currently have :

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 85% 15%;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 23px 54% 34% 50px;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.userInfo {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  background-color: #585858;
}

.userInfo div {
  margin: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}

.task {
  background: white;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 0px black solid;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.taskList {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 577px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.taskModel {
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.info {
  text-align: left;
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.create {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 2;
}

dx-scheduler {
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <button>
      <span style="color: #790614; font-weight: bold;">Bug</span> or 
      <span style="color: #ff9d00">Change Request</span>
    </button>
    <button>Configuration</button>
    <button>Export CSV</button>
    <button>
      <span>Vacations</span><br />
      <span style="color: #d1d1d1">Absences</span> 
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="userInfo">
    <div>
      <span style="color: white; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
        Username
      </span>
      <button  style="height: 28px;">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="dx-scheduler">
  <div>A calendar</div>
</div>
  
  <div class="task">
    <div style="height:23px;display: grid;grid-template-columns: 100%">      
      <input name="taskFilterText" type="text" placeholder="Search"
             style="float: left; margin-right: 25px;border: 0;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="taskList">
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
    <p>Repeat me</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="taskModel">
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
    <p>Repeat after me</p>
  </div>

  <div class="info">
    <div style="margin-top: 2px;">
      <div style="margin-top: 3px;float: left">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">H. remanining sickness</span>
        
      </div>

      <div style="margin-top: 2px;float: left">
        <input type="checkbox"
        style="margin: 0px 4px 0px 20px;width: 18px;height: 18px;"/><span style="float:right;margin-top: 1px;">Count today.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="create">
    <div>
        <button>+ model</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

They are all DIV except for the dx-scheduler that is a component. I also want to say that .taskList and .taskModel needs to have scrollbars since it contains a list of items.
Is there some way that my 50px for the last row works?

Edit : I've put HTML so it could show the problem in action.

Comment: read about `fr` unit

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've put a working sample now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, subtract the last row from one of the other % rows
You want your rows to equal 100% for what you are trying to do.

```
    grid-template-rows: 55px 23px calc(66% - 128px) 34% 50px;
```

[fiddle with example](https://jsfiddle.net/94yw76dj/)

Comment: I didn't know that calc existed in css, this is exactly what I wanted. This is a relief to know it can be done after so many hours trying to make it works.